# Render components conditionally, based on items of deeply nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component that's receiving a data object returned from an API response.

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a field from that data response, checks an element inside of that field and iterates over it checking each object inside the array for the value of a specific alert.

If a value for a specific alert is found I need to render an Icon for that alert.

The data object looks like this:

```
location: {
  ...,
details: {
  summary: [
            {
             type: 'calling',
             icon: 'phone' 
             },
             {
             type: 'power',
             icon: 'electric' 
             },
             {
             type: 'water',
             icon: 'water-icon' 
             },
           ]
        }
      }
```

And here's the section where I'm trying to conditionally render the icons (this was my first pass and rudimentary attempt):

```
           <div>
            {location.alertDetails && (
                <IconBox title={`Alerts`}>
                  <IconSection>
                  {location.details.summary.includes(type === calling) && 
                   <CallIcon />
                   }
                   {location.details.summary.includes(type === power) && 
                   <ElectricIcon />
                   }
                  {location.details.summary.includes(type === water) && 
                   <WaterIcon />
                  }
                  </IconSection>
                </IconBox>
              )}
            </div>
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov yeup!

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov receive it as a prop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may store within components state the array of fetched types:

```
const [types, setTypes] = useState(location.details.summary.map(({type}) => type))
```

With that, you may simply render (or not) your icons conditionally:

```
 <div>
  {location.alertDetails && (
      <IconBox title={`Alerts`}>
        <IconSection>
           {types.includes('calling') && <CallIcon />} 
           {types.includes('power') && <ElectricIcon />}
           {types.includes('water') && <WaterIcon />}
        </IconSection>
      </IconBox>
    )}
  </div>
```

Here's the demo (with all of your components rendered as a `<div>`'s, since I dont have those):

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState } = React
      
const apiData = {location:{details:{summary:[{type:'calling',icon:'phone'},{type:'power',icon:'electric'},{type:'water',icon:'water-icon'},]}}}    
      
const IconTray = ({data}) => {
  const [types, setTypes] = useState(data.location.details.summary.map(({type}) => type))
  return (
     <div>
        {data.location.details && (
            <div>
              <div>
                 {types.includes('calling') && <div>I am a CallIcon</div>} 
                 {types.includes('power') && <div>I am an ElectronIcon</div>}
                 {types.includes('water') && <div>I am a WaterIcon</div>}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
     </div>
  )
}

render (
  <IconTray data={apiData} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error where the hooks are declared saying ```object is possibly null or undefined``` for location.details in ```useState(location.details.```

Comment: This would have worked, but I overlooked something in the current architecture of my application that forced me to take another approach. Thank you for the answer though and for for the clarity regarding on ```.includes()```!

Comment: @Josh : you're most welcome, will gladly support you if (hopefully, not;) you stumble somewhere along the way with your current architecture

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to easily iterate over these -

```
 <div>
   {location.alertDetails && location.details.summary.map(item =>{ item.icon && return  (
                <IconBox title={`Alerts`}>
                  <IconSection>
                  {location.details.summary.includes(type === calling) && 
                   <CallIcon />
                   }
                   {location.details.summary.includes(type === power) && 
                   <ElectricIcon />
                   }
                  {location.details.summary.includes(type === water) && 
                   <WaterIcon />
                  }
                  </IconSection>
                </IconBox>
    )})}
 </div>
```

Comment: It is [recommended](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to assign `key` property when rendering multiple elements. You can really benefit from `map()` when render multiple uniform elements, in your answer it doesn't reduce code lines, moreover it adds unnecessary overhead.